# How to generate AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encrypted cipher in angularJs

Tags: java, cryptography

I am working on a feature which require Aes encrypted (AES/CBC/PKCS5padding) cipher text to be sent from client to server which has ASP.Net in backend.

I've a decryption function on the server side as below :

```
 public static string Decrypt(string inputBase64, string passphrase = null)
                {
                    byte[] key, iv = new byte[0];
                    byte[] base64data = Convert.FromBase64String(inputBase64);
                    byte[] passphrasedata = RawBytesFromString(passphrase);
                    byte[] currentHash = new byte[0];
                    SHA256Managed hash = new SHA256Managed();
                    currentHash = hash.ComputeHash(passphrasedata);
                    return DecryptStringFromBytes(base64data, currentHash, null);
                }



static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments. 
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            //if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            //  throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

            // Declare the string used to hold 
            // the decrypted text. 
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
            // with the specified key and IV. 
            using (var cipher = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                cipher.Key = Key;
                cipher.IV = new byte[16];
                //cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                //cipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = cipher.CreateDecryptor(Key, cipher.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption. 
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        var bytes = default(byte[]);
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            bytes = srDecrypt.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(srDecrypt.ReadToEnd());

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                            // and place them in a string.
                            //aintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                        plaintext = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Count());
                    }
                }

            }

            return plaintext;

        }
```

I want to implement an angularjs alternative to the following android code :

```
public static String Encrypt(String input, String passphrase)
    {
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("") || passphrase.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return "";
        else
        {
            byte[] key, iv;

            byte[] passphrasedata = null;
            try
            {
                passphrasedata = passphrase.getBytes("UTF-8");
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] currentHash = new byte[0];
            MessageDigest md = null;
            try
            {
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            currentHash = md.digest(passphrasedata);

            iv = new byte[16];
            return Base64.encodeToString(EncryptStringToBytes(input, currentHash, iv), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        }
    }

static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(String plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        if (plainText == null || plainText.length() <= 0)
        {
            Log.e("error", "plain text empty");
        }
        if (Key == null || Key.length <= 0)
        {
            Log.e("error", "key is empty");
        }
        if (IV == null || IV.length <= 0)
        {
            Log.e("error", "IV key empty");
        }
        byte[] encrypted;

        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(Key, "AES");
            IvParameterSpec IVKey = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, IVKey);

            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return encrypted;
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (BadPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The Android code above is working fine. I want to implement the same encryption logic at AngularJs.

I've included CryptoJS library for SHA-256 and AES cipher calculation. Here is the code which I've implemented.

```
var password = '12345678';
var passwordHash = CryptoJS.SHA256(password).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1);
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('0000000000000000');                                                                       
var cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext,passwordHash,{
                            iv: iv,
                            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                            keySize: 256/32,
                            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
                            });
cipherText = cipher.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

The problem is that, the encoded string cannot be decrypted back to its previous form. I think there is some mismatch in the encryption logic in the client side and decryption logic on the server side.

When I pass the CryptoJS encrypted cipher to java decryption function, it shows  errors:

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

or sometimes:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Comment: looks like your IV are of different sizes, 32bytes in JS and 16 in c#

Comment: You're using UTF-8 in C# and Java, but use Latin1 for some reason in JS.

Comment: @BhavO : i've changed IV to 16bytes, still not working.  
I've given Latin1 to make it 32byte string. If i convert it to UTF-8, the length of the string will become  more than 32bytes. Aes expects 32byte key (256bit)

Comment: can you update answer, with any new errors thanks

Comment: @BhavO: I've updated IV to 16bytes. The errors are same. I doubt if it is an error with padding. I got an error 'Given final block not properly padded' when I pasted my cipher into an online AES decryption algorithm.

Comment: @ArtjomB. : I've given Latin1 to make it 32byte string. If i convert it to UTF-8, the length of the string will become more than 32bytes. Aes expects 32byte key (256bit)

Comment: Remove the `.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1)` completely.

Comment: On the Js side your setting the keysize to 8 (256/32), the once the password is hashed its larger then the 8 byte password, the server side is using the length of key to derive key size

Comment: @ArtjomB. : Thanks!!! it worked!!  I thought i should pass it as 32byte string. But it worked when I pass hex code from SHA-256. Really thanks... closing the problem.

Comment: Hi, How can we generate public key and private key for a user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks guys!!!, I got it working with the following code.

```
    function hash (){
       return CryptoJS.SHA256(password);
    }
    var cipher = (function(plaintext, password) {
                        passwordHash = hash(password);
                        var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('0000000000000000');
                        var cipher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, passwordHash, {
                            iv: iv,
                            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                            keySize: 256 / 32,
                            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
                        });
                        return cipher;
    })(plaintext, password);

   cipherBase64 =  cipher.ciphertext.toString().hex2a().base64Encode();
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting error `cipher.ciphertext.toString(...).hex2a is not a function` on the last line. Can you help ? Umm... I am using JQM. Is it something particularly related to AngularJS only ?

Comment: same here with react-native

Comment: Hi, How can we generate public key and private key for a user?